# Apple Script: Copy specific string from Text and Paste in another location on the same page

Tags: javascript, applescript

Very sorry as I m very new to this and I hope I explain it perfectly

I have a form where in I have input the text so I could copy specific item from it and paste it at another location in the same webpage.

Example 2.80 VV Light Weight Size 999 03 Oval 10x8
This is what appears in the input text of a box which I have entered, I would like to copy 2.80 and paste it in another form on the same webpage.
Then I would like to copy 10 from Oval and put in another location and copy 8 and put in another form.

Is that possible with applescript?

All help would be highly highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

if you know the ids of the form elements you can do something like this:-

```
tell application "Safari"
  activate
  tell current tab of window 1
    set myValue to do JavaScript "document.getElementById('fieldX').value;"
    do JavaScript "document.getElementById('fieldY').value = '" & myValue & "';"
  end tell
end tell
```